# Why nginx is complaining about 55555 as Invalid port in nginx listen directive?

Tags: nginx

I have `nginx v1.6.2` configuration with listen `192.168.128.105:55555` working fine.

I'm trying to verify same configuration against `nginx v1.10.3` and it is giving me following error,

```
nginx:[emerg] invalid port in "192.168.128.105:55555" of the "listen" directive in ...nginx.conf:39
```

Looked at the [nginx listen doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) but I can't find any information about this error. **Edit-1** following is the nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;         #v1.10.3 - error 1 is invalid number

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    #worker_connections  1024;   #v1.10.3 - error 1024 is invalid number
}


http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    #keepalive_timeout 65;      #v1.10.3 - error 65 is invalid value
    #types_hash_max_size 2048;  #v1.10.3 - error 2048 is invalid number

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_disable    "msie6";
    #gzip                   off;
    #gzip_proxied   off;
    #chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    server {
           listen          192.168.128.105:55555;
           server_name     192.168.128.105:55555;

           location / {                        
                    proxy_buffering     off;
                    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    #proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For '$http_x_forwarded_for, $realip_remote_addr';
                    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto http;
                    proxy_pass          http://192.168.3.2/;
           }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Show (at least) line 39 of your configuration file

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, Added `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Does it work with `listen 55555;` ?

Comment: Does your system have the address 192.168.128.105 active?

Comment: nginx considers any port from 1 to 65535 as valid, might this be an encoding problem with the config file?

Comment: @RichardSmith - No `listen 55555` doesn't work. @deagh - the network interface is active. It doesn't complain if I run test against `nginx v1.6.2`

Comment: You probably don't need server_name, and if you have it in there it doesn't need IP and port. That's what the listen directive is for.